# How to write concise JSDoc using AMD modules and factory-style constructors?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying to add JSDoc in to a project where the majority of sources follow the following guidelines:

- Scripts are AMD modules which define classes (they export a constructor function )
- Constructors are really factories; they return anonymous objects (instead of populating `this`) to avoid undesired behavior if `new` is omitted.

I would like to document this using JSDoc, but "getting it right" currently involves what seems to be a lot of redundancy:

```
/**
 * These are my docs for SomeClass.
 * @module path/to/some-module
 */
define(
    /** @lends module:path/to/some-module */
    function () {

        /**
         * Construct some object.
         * @constructor
         */
        function SomeClass(a, b, c) {
            var somePrivateVariable;

            function somePrivateFunction() {}

            return {
                /** @memberof module:path/to/some-module~SomeClass# */
                someMethod: function () {},

                /** @memberof module:path/to/some-module~SomeClass# */
                someOtherMethod: function () {}
            };
        }
        return SomeClass;
    }
);
```

I'd like to shorten this. In particular, the long "path" after all those `@memberof` tags is tedious and noisy, especially when there are a lot of methods. The `@lends` is also annoying, since from a human-reader perspective it's totally redundant.

Is there a better way to do this without rewriting or refactoring the code itself?